Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at L60
I'm facing this null object error even though I have checked the "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)" and by commenting the onClick methods the app works fine.
The idea is simple, all I want is to get the image into a intent then process it to identify it
Here is the code:
package com.example.letmeguess;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.example.letmeguess.ml.MobilenetV110224Quant;

import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button sB, pB, cB;
    TextView result;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sB =(android.widget.Button) findViewById(R.id.selectB);
        pB =(android.widget.Button) findViewById(R.id.PredicteB);
        cB =(android.widget.Button) findViewById(R.id.captureB);
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        sB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent1.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent1,10);
            }
        });

        cB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent2, 12);
            }
        });

        // permission
        getPermission();
        int cnt = 0;

        String[] lables = new String[1001];

        try {

            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("labels.txt")));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                lables[cnt] = line;
                cnt++;
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    MobilenetV110224Quant model = MobilenetV110224Quant.newInstance(MainActivity.this);

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.UINT8);
                    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 224, 224, true);
                    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(TensorImage.fromBitmap(bm).getBuffer());

                    // Runs model inference and gets result.
                    MobilenetV110224Quant.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                    result.setText(lables[getMax(outputFeature0.getFloatArray())]+" ");

                    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle the exception
                }

            }
        });



    }

    int getMax(float[] arr){
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[max]) max = i;
        }
        return max;
    }

    void getPermission(){
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},11);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 11){
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    this.getPermission();
                }
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==10){
            if(data!=null){
                try {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(requestCode == 12){
            bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}

and the layout.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Image Classify"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Select Image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/selectB"
        android:text="Capture" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PredicteB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/captureB"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Predicte" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Result:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/PredicteB"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>

commenting the onClick makes the app works but of course that is not the solution

Move your findViewById() calls to be after your setContentView() call. You need to inflate the activity layout first before you can retrieve the widgets that were inflated.

Unbelievable.... commonsWare you saved me and thanks for your efforts.... I'm new with android studio and java and never thought that such thing could impact the results this way
